# python generator expression change value

Tags: python, generator

I want to make a function that return a generator exp.
I tried to do something like this:

```
return (f(value) value=f(value) for i in itertools.count(1))
```

but it does not work.
I want every next step the value the value receive the last value.
f this is function that make some calculations on value.

ok I have function:

```
def f(num):
    return num*num
```

I want to make new function that return generator expression. 
something like this:

```
  def genE(f,value)
     return (f(value) value=f(value) for i in itertools.count(1))
```

so if I call genE:

```
for i in genE(f,3):
    print (i)
```

it will print 3 9 81 81^2...
the function f could be another function
    [value, f(value), f(f(value)), f(f(f(value)))...]

Comment: Could you please explain the question with an example?

Comment: ok I have fucntion
    def f(num):
      return num*num
I want to make new function that return generator expresion 
something like this
    def genE(f,value)
       return (f(value) value=f(value) for i in itertools.count(1))
so if I call genE
   for i in genE(f,3):
       print (i)
it will print 3 9 81 81^2...
the function f could be another function

Comment: Please explain it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

not totally clear on what you mean.  you have a value:

```
value = ...
```

and a function:

```
def f (value):
     ...
```

and you want to return a new list:

```
[value, f(value), f(f(value)), f(f(f(value)))...]
```

so i think what you want (for length of list `i`) is...

```
def g (value, i):
    if i > 0:
        yield value
        g(f(value), i-1)
```

Comment: I need this to be infinate and also I must have this is generator Expresion
and this is what I need 
[value, f(value), f(f(value)), f(f(f(value)))...]

Comment: @user2999009 Take a look at my answer.

Comment: you cannot store an infinite list.  if you're looking to retrieve the `i`th value, rewrite g to remove yield and return when i == 0

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a generator expression, use a generator function:

```
def iterate(f, value):
    while True:
        yield value
        value=f(value)
```

The `yield` keyword marks the point at which a value will be "generated". When `iterate` is called, it will return a generator object.

You'll likely want to read about [fixed point combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) and related topics, because there's a lot of learning about the sort of thing you're doing.

Here it is in use:

```
import itertools
powers = iterate(lambda n:n*n, 3)
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n <= 30000, powers))
#=>[3, 9, 81, 6561]
```